# .htaccess: Deny from all

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

This is working:

```
<Files *.fileext>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
</Files>
```

This is not:

```
<Files *.fileext|somedirectory>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Deny from all
</Files>
```

Please help.

Comment: https://locallost.net/?p=129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Files` does not allow the use of regular expressions, but `FilesMatch` does, therefore it searches for a file with (something).fileext|somedirectory in the path, and this is not what you want to do. Your code will have to look like this:

```
<FilesMatch (\.fileext$|^somedirectory$)>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#files and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Answer (score 0):

This can be slightly improved.
There is no need for an order directive and the end of string syntax can be used just once.

```
<FilesMatch (\.fileext|^somedirectory)$>
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```